# Javascript element addEventListener (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have this code :

```
let label = document.getElementsByClassName('gegegege');
console.log(label[0]);
```

Console shows my div. But when I try to add an event listener to it like so:

```
label[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("You knocked?");
});
```

...., nothing happens. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: [Not reproduceable](https://jsfiddle.net/dey41rxo/). What exactly did you expect to happen? I mean just attaching an event to an element doesn't do anything whih would show up on a page ...

Comment: you have to click that element to see something happening..

Comment: yes, when i click no second console log ("you knocked?")

Comment: "_no second console_" But there is, please take a look at the end of the logged line ... or at the beginning, if you're on Chrome.

Comment: @JSpadawan second console log? o.0

Comment: Are you looking to the left side of the the text `"you knocked?"` where the counter should be increasing? If the same `click` event causes duplicate messages in the console, a new message doesn't get printed - it just increments a counter to the left of the message

Comment: if you can see that div on console log, just put the second code immediately after the first code... and click the element the contains the class at the page, not on console window.

Comment: It is right under it ...and when i click on element no new console log...

Comment: @Teemu where ? when i click on that div, no new console log

Comment: Look at the end of the log line (or beginning), there's a counter, which shows how many times the same text has been logged.

Comment: No, the log "You knocked?" its not there.. only first console log `console.log(label[0]);` is working..

Comment: Did you run the linked fiddle? Please add all the relevant code to the post, if you can't get your own code to work.

Comment: Wait! Are you testing with Internet Explorer? If so, you should see an error message complaining about the arrow function. If that's the case, use a regular function expression instead of the arrow function.

Comment: @Teemu i am sorry, my DIV is created dynamically and not in DOM from beginning

Comment: Please show the relevant code, all the HTML, JS and CSS needed to reproduce your problem. This is not going to lead anywhere without the code.